# The notion of "sheaf of functions" for projective varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am working through a book on linear algebraic groups, and without giving background and just at one single point the notion of a *sheaf of a function* is used. I never heard of that. I know what an algebraic variety is, and I know some commutative algebra, which is also mentioned in the book. But when I try to look up what is meant by this "sheaf" I am totally lost, and even the wikipedia article is quite long.

So, could anyone explain shortly for this specific situation why we need a sheaf in the following construction, and whats the intuition behind it?

The relevant section of the books is:

> [...] projective $n$-space $\mathbb P^n$ may be defined as the set of equivalence classes of $k^{n+1} \setminus \{ (0,0,\ldots,0) \}$ modulo the diagonal action of $k^{\times}$ by multiplication. Taking common zeros of a collection of homogeneous polynomials in $k[T_0, T_1, \ldots, T_n]$ as closed sets defines a topology on $\mathbb P^n$. A *projective variety* is then a closed subset of $\mathbb P^n$ equipped with the induced topology.
>
> The $k$-algebra of regular function on an affine variety here needs to be replaced by a *sheaf of a function*, as follows: First, for $X$ an irreducible affine variety and $x \in X$, let $I(x) \unlhd k[X]$ be the ideal of functions vanishing at $x$ and let $\mathcal O_x$ be the localization of $k[X]$ with respect to the prime ideal $I(x)$. Then setting $O_X = \bigcap_{x\in X} O_x$, for $U \subseteq X$ open, defines a sheaf of functions $\mathcal O_X$ on $X$. Clearly the fields of fractions of $\mathcal O_X(U)$ and $k[X]$ agree. More generally, if $X$ is reducible, say $X = X_1 \cup \ldots X_n$ with irreducible components $X_i$, then setting
>   $$
>  O_X(U) := \{ f : U \to k \mid f_{|U\cap X_i} \in \mathcal O_{X_i}(U\cap X_i) \},
> $$
>   for $U \subseteq X$ open, defines a sheaf on $X$. One can show that $O_X(X) = k[X]$, the usual $k$-algebra of regular functions on $X$.

I cannot make sense of all these construction. These construction are used in the book to show that linear algebraic groups admit quotients that are algebraic

Comment: I believe you have to go through the definition of a sheaf. This is not a difficult notion and it is a very basic object in algebraic geometry. The point is : if $X$ is a projective variety, then there are only constant functions on it. But if you consider the assignment "Open subset $U \mapsto $ function defined on $U$", you get something non trivial. And this object is exactly the sheaf $U\mapsto\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

Comment: The wikipedia article is indeed a bit long, but you can read only the definitions of presheaves, sheaves, morphisms, and of course the examples to have some in mind. There are plenty of books on the subject and most book on algebraic geometry define the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ for a projective variety.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, but why is every function on a projective variety constant?

Comment: I don't know your background in algebraic geometry. But think of projective varieties as compact. If $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^1$ is a function on $X$, then its image must be a compact subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$. But only the finite subset are compact, so $f$ is constant. In fact, this argument is perfectly valid, but the right terminology is "proper".

Comment: Always transfer projective to affine. My way of thinking this is intersecting this projective variety with standard chart $x_i\neq 0$ for some $i$. And you know all regular functions on affine variety coincide with its coordinate ring which are basically polynomials quotienting out the elements vanishing on the affine variety. Now pull it back to projective variety through homogenization. You see the functions are all homogeneous polynomials. This cannot define a function unless this is a constant function. You are mapping class of elements to a number.